# Alerta sonoro em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tenho que criar um alerta sonoro para uma aplicação de chat, estou utilizar a biblioteca de audio nativa do javascript, o problema é que muitas vezes, esse alerta é bloqueado pelo navegador, isso aconteceu quando o usuário carrega a pagina e não interage com ela (isso tem acontecido muito por sinal).
o seguinte erro é exibido no console

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Sei que existe a possiblidade de forçar o cara a clicar em algo assim que abrir a pagina, mas o projeto já está quase pronto, e o meu chefe não enxerga isso com bons olhos.

Sendo assim, alguém saberia se tem uma saída melhor, algo parecido com os alertas visuais, que o navegador pergunta se o cara permiti o site enviar.
ou alguma outra solução, não sei.

Código responsável pelo alerta

```
function play_sound(thesound)
{    
    let audio = new Audio(base_url + '/media/mp3/' + thesound + '.mp3');
    audio.muted = true;
    var playPromise = audio.play();
    if (playPromise != undefined) {
        playPromise.then(_ => {                  
            audio.pause();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);  
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostre como está seu código, amigo.

Comment: O erro já diz tudo. Você não pode dar `play` em uma _media_ (como áudio) se o usuário não tiver interagido com a página antes. Não tem muito o que fazer além de acatar com a "limitação" (de segurança, aliás) da plataforma.

Comment: @WeslleyAraújo, Desculpe, já adicionei a parte do código que faz o alerta amigo.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, infelizmente estou chegando a essa conclusão, só acho que a plataforma deveria possibilitar uma forma do usuário permitir receber alerta de um determinado site, no caso da minha aplicação (chat), é comum o operador abrir o terminal e ficar aguardando um chamado, sem interagir com ela antes, enfim, acho que vou ter que força uma maneira de força o cara interagir com a pagina ao abri-la. Mas isso me deixa uma duvida, o cara interagiu mas ficou uma hora sem fazer nada, o navegador vai voltar a bloquear o alerta sonoro?, ou isso acontece apenas quando carrega a pagina?

Comment: Não sei, não parece claro. Por vocês querem emitir um efeito sonoro assim que a página carrega e o usuário nem interagiu com ela ainda? Consegue explicar melhor o cenário?

Comment: @Raizant, é um chat, imagina o seguinte, o operador clica em atender chat e uma nova aba é aberta com o terminal de atendimento, geralmente, antes de receber o primeiro chamado, o operador ainda não fez nenhuma interação com a página, fazendo com que o primeiro atendimento do dia não seja notificado.